# How to get each column value of arraylist in android?

Tags: java

In my arraylist I am storing lot of data. When I am getting the data for example **myarraylist.get(0)** it means it is displaying the entire row. But I need to **get each column of that row**. How can I do that...please help me regarding this...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Dude we need to know what type of Java object your List consist of.

Comment: Hi my arraylist is of string type...ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ourstringList1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the values by `iterating` using a for loop with an inner for loop.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> row = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> column = new ArrayList<String>();

column.add("column1");
column.add("column2");
row.add(column);

  for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < column.size(); j++) {
           Log.d("values", row.get(i).get(j));
        }
     }
```

Comment: Hi I have given like this....for (int i = 0; i < ourstringList1.size(); i++) {  for (int j = 0; j < ourstringList1.size(); j++) {            System.out.println("values"+ourstringList1.get(i).get(j));
            } for each row i have 5 columns but it is displaying only 3 columns for each row...where i went wrong?
        }

Comment: see carefully you are applying *ourstringList1.size()* in both the for loops outer and inner. In the inner for loop apply the column ArrayList.size().

Answer (score 4):

if it is `ArrayList<ArrayList<object>>`, use `myarraylist.get(row).get(column);`